# How can I fix ggarrange error "error in p$x: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" when "p" nor "x" exist in the workspace?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to combine plots so I can easily export them to a pdf where they can be compared to each other. I had already combined the duo's of graphs into a single plot with ggarrange, but now I want to put those below each other so they're all in one place. The problem is that when I try to add more plots to it, it gives a confusing error saying that $ can't be used on an atomic vector, but that vector isn't in the list of objects.

Here's my code:

```
ggarrange(PlotWLm1, PlotWLm2, PlotWLm3, ncol = 1, nrow = 3)
```

And here's the error

`Error in p$x : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

I've tried to remove certain specifications, to some success. If I remove the ncol and nrow it works, but predictably it doesn't have the number of columns I want it to have (that being only 1).

If I only remove nrow or ncol, I still get the same error.

I tried starting from the base plots. If I use both ncol and nrow, I get the same error as before, but if I only use ncol I get the following:

Input:

```
ggarrange(MeWLm1, PWLm1, MeWLm2, PWLm2, MeWLm3, PWLm3, ncol = 2)
```

Output
`$`1`

$`2`

$`3`

attr(,"class")
[1] "list"      "ggarrange"`

And it plotted only the last two plots.

Does anyone know why it gives that error, or where that p$x came from? I've never created any object named `p` in this project, so I think it's an internal thing. I can't see it anywhere in the work environment either.

Comment: Difficult to help without a proper reproducible example. The easiest solution would be to not use ggarrange, but the patchwork package instead. It's syntax is also much more intuitive

Comment: Are these all ggplots? Do they plot fine individually?

Comment: @tjebo 's suggestion worked! Patchwork is a really nice package for this. I still don't know where that p$x error came from, but I can continue now.

Answer (score 0):

Using the patchwork package worked. As @tjebo said, it's much more intuitive. Instead of the ncol and nrow for ggarrange, it requires you to manually place your plots in a certain position relative to the others like this:

```
    PlotsHH <-
(MeHHm1 | PHHm1)/
(MeHHm2 | PHHm2)/
(MeHHm3 | PHHm3)
PlotsHH
```

Which gives this result:

[Plots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jasAS.png)

Thanks!

Comment: You can also just add them and then use `plot_layout`. if your plots share the same legend, you could use  `+ plot_layout(guides = "collect")`. You will need to ensure that all legends are exactly the same - same name, same breaks, same limits. (you have currently different limits for some). You can harmonise this with scale_ functions